# How does Grails handles between constraints and messages.properites

Tags: validation, grails, internationalization, bigdecimal, grails-domain-class

In my grails 2.3.11 project, I want to show `Please enter a positive numeric value for salary`on my screen if the negative value is inputted. But it displayed `Property [salary] with value [-9] is less than minimum value [0]`

Constraints in my domain class

```
BigDecimal salary
static constraints = {
    salary nullable: false, min:0 as BigDecimal, scale: 2
}
```

Messages.properties

```
default.invalid.min.message=Property [{0}] with value [{2}] is less than minimum value [{3}]

employee.salary.invalid.min.message=Please enter a positive value for salary
```

I think the second line in the messages.properties is wrong, help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the message, you would need

```
employee.salary.min.notmet=Please enter a positive value for salary
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Frederic It works, You save my time :)